# How to install HouseNumbering Plugin for QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am trying to install the HouseNumbering Plugin for QGIS 3.2 but I am getting an error that this plugin is only valid for QGIS 2-2.9. Is there a specific plugin available for QGIS 3.2 or can I make changes to the current plugin and use it somehow?

Comment: It's not compatiable with QGIS 3.2. So, you can't install.

Comment: Only way is to customize the plugin completely for QGIS 3

Comment: What did you need the housenumbering plugin to do? There may be another method to achieve it.

Answer (score 7):

HouseNumbering plugin is not compatible with QGIS 3.2 because it relies on python 2 and QGIS 3.x relies on python 3. The latest update to the [HouseNumbering plugin](https://github.com/marcobra/HouseNumbering) was 4 years ago, which makes it not yet compatible with QGIS 3.

You can download the source code from the github and modify it if you know how to code using python 3 and then share your code with the author to update the source code in github.